# Invoke a React custom hook inside the class component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am able to see a lot of threads explaining how to use a custom hook inside a class component using a higher-order component, In that case, we are using a Hooks output value inside the class component.

Is there any way we can invoke a hook inside the class component while using HOC? because sometimes the hooks are accepting some parameters. and the parameters for that function are based on the state of a class component

**Accessing the hook value inside the class component**

```
import React from 'react';
import { withSampleHookHoc } from './withSampleHookHoc';
    
class SampleClassComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          name: 'Guest',
        };
    }
    render() {
        return <h1> Sample Class Component - {this.props.name} </h1>;
    }
}
    
export default withSampleHookHoc(SampleClassComponent);
```

**But what I want to have is passing the state value as a parameter to the hook and invoking it from the class component**

```
import React from 'react';
import { withSampleHookHoc } from './withSampleHookHoc';

class SampleClassComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          text: 'Guest',
        };
    }
    render() {
        return <h1> Sample Class Component - {this.props.name(this.state.text)} </h1>;
    }
}
    
export default withSampleHookHoc(SampleClassComponent);
```

[Code URL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-avxrmp?file=src/Components/SampleClassComponent.js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you certainly can. Stackblitz example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bgum6q?file=src/Components/SampleClassComponent.js. Edit the input then click the `Update name` button to see it works.

Essentially, you just return some function from your hook, which will be passed to the class component as a prop via the HOC. Then, you have access to this function inside your class component and can do whatever you like.

If you have any questions, just add a comment to this answer.

Answer (score 4):

From the [React Hooks FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-hooks-classes-or-a-mix-of-both):

> You can’t use Hooks inside a class component, but you can definitely
> mix classes and function components with Hooks in a single tree.
> Whether a component is a class or a function that uses Hooks is an
> implementation detail of that component. In the longer term, we expect
> Hooks to be the primary way people write React components.

In other words, you can create a functional component that takes in your class' state values as props, calls a hook using those values, and renders some output.